# ¿Cómo mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de mi ciclo for?

Tags: r, loops, data, eficiencia

El siguiente `for` funciona y hace lo que quiero, el problema es que tarda mucho, esto es un pequeño ejemplo pero cuando lo hago con un número mayor de datos tarda mucho y me gustaría que fuera mas eficiente.

Basicamente lo que quiero es que si `FLAG` toma como valor `A`, la nueva variable `VALOR2` sea `VALOR` pero si `FLAG` no es `A`, quiero que tome el valor que tiene cuando `FLAG` es `A`, se me ocurrió ir arrastrando el valor anterior de manera que coja el valor de `VALOR2` de la fila anterior. Problema que tarda mucho.

```
FLAG <- c("A","B","C","A","D","D")
VALOR <- c("GRA","VE","DT","RT","MM","SS")

datos <- data.table(FLAG,VALOR)
datos <- datos[,VALOR2:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))]
for (i in 1:nrow(datos)){
  datos$VALOR2[i] <- ifelse(datos$FLAG[i]=='A',datos$VALOR[i],datos$VALOR2[i-1])
}
```

El primer valor de `FLAG` siempre va a ser `A`, así que no hay que pensar en que pasaría sino es `A` el primer valor.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Usando `apply()`

Una forma podría ser reemplazando tu ciclo explícito por uno implícito, usando `apply()`:

```
last <- datos[1,"VALOR"]
datos$VALOR2 <- apply(datos, MARGIN=1, FUN = function(x) {if (x[1]=='A') {last<<-x[2]};last})
```

Explicación:

- Creamos una variable `last` para mantener el último `valor`, lo inicializamos con el primero de la tabla (has indicado que el primero siempre es un `FLAG == 'A'`)
- Aplicamos a la tabla por fila (`MARGIN=1`) una función con la lógica para obtener el `VALOR2`. Nota que para establecer el valor de `last` usamos `<<-` ya que se trata de una variable global en el contexto de `apply()`.

#### 2. Usando `cumsum()`

Otra forma interesante, muy compacta y elegante, sería:

```
datos$VALOR2 <- datos[datos$FLAG=='A', 2][cumsum(datos$FLAG=='A')]
```

Explicación:

- Con `cumsum()` hacemos una suma acumulativa de cada valor de los grupos dónde  `FLAG=='A'` lo cual nos termina dando un vector del tipo `c(1,1,1,2,2,2)` por lo que luego simplemente retornaremos un vector con los valores correspondientes a esos índices.

#### Resultados:

En cuanto a performance, hay una mejora no diría que abismal pero si significativa en la opción 1. Podríamos verificarlo:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

FLAG <- c("A","B","C","A","D","D")
VALOR <- c("GRA","VE","DT","RT","MM","SS")
datos <- data.table(FLAG,VALOR)
datos <- datos[,VALOR2:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))]

test.1 <- function(datos) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(datos)){
        datos$VALOR2[i] <- ifelse(datos$FLAG[i]=='A',datos$VALOR[i],datos$VALOR2[i-1])
    }
}

test.2 <- function(datos) {
    last <- datos[1,"VALOR"]
    datos$VALOR2 <- apply(datos, MARGIN=1, FUN = function(x) {if (x[1]=='A') {last<<-x[2]};last})
}

test.3 <- function(datos) {
    datos$VALOR2 <- datos[datos$FLAG=='A', 2][cumsum(datos$FLAG=='A')]
}

microbenchmark(test.1(datos),test.2(datos),test.3(datos))

Unit: microseconds
          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 test.1(datos) 565.085 695.5795 702.4884 705.8430 711.5615 1053.633   100   c
 test.2(datos) 330.489 340.7520 347.2064 342.9515 348.9630  402.041   100 a  
 test.3(datos) 420.515 431.3650 479.0263 436.6435 442.2150 3414.849   100  b
```

Casi un 30% de mejora en la opción 1, esto puede variar en función del volumen de datos, y puede que la opción 2 vaya mejorando su performance.

Comment: Muchas gracias!
El tiempo se ha reducido de una manera increible, con cualquiera de las dos soluciones lo hace al momento algo que antes tardaba más de media hora.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de inicio se resolvió correctamente pero con el tiempo me ha surgido un nuevo problema.

```
datos <- datos[,VALOR3:=rep("vacio",nrow(datos))] for (i in 2:nrow(datos)){ if(datos$FLAG[i]=='B' & datos$FLAG[i-1]=='A') datos$valor3[i-1] <- datos$valor[i] }
```

Es decir, quiero eliminar el `for`, y no se como adaptar la solución que me disteis con anterioridad para que lea valores de la siguiente fila. Gracias.